# border-bottom does not change when active

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the active buttons bottom border to be white, not sure if it's because i am calling two divs that different border bottom color.

```
.navigation a {
    line-height:25px;
}

#navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: clip;
  height: 26px;
  padding-bottom:26px;
}
.navigation a.active-link {
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    color: black;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
  <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
      <a href="/" class="active-link">Show all</a>
       <a href="#" >title</a>
    <a href="#" >title1</a>
    <a href="#" >title2</a>
    <a href="#" >title3</a>
    <a href="#" >title4</a>
    <a href="#" >title5</a>
    <a href="#" >title6</a>
    <a href="#" >title7</a>
    <a href="#" >title8</a>
    <a href="#" >title9</a>
    <a href="#" >title10</a>  
    <a href="#" >title11</a>
    <a href="#" >title12</a>  
    <a href="#" >title13</a>
    <a href="#" >title14</a>
    <a href="#" >title15</a>
    <a href="#" >title16</a>  
    <a href="#" >title17</a>
    <a href="#" >title18</a>
    <a href="#" >title19</a>
    <a href="#" >title20</a>
    <a href="#" >title21</a>
    <a href="#" >title22</a>
    <a href="#" >title23</a>
    <a href="#" >title24</a>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akn5r7y5/7/  and what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the active and none active look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/os7Qx.jpg

Comment: What is this `background-border: #red;`

Comment: sorry about that my dyslexia must of gotten me

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan done thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the adjusted CSS for what you are trying to accomplish. We move each link down by 1px so it is covering the bottom line. Then we set a white background on the active link so it covers the line only for that one. See the fiddle link below for the final result.

```
.navigation a {
    line-height:26px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}
.navigation a.active-link {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    color: #666;
    background-color: white;
}
.container {
  height: 48px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#navigation {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  height: 48px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akn5r7y5/12/

Comment: but that breaks the reason why I'm using the overflow control there.  Is there no way to do it without having to take that out? As you notice the text starts to stack if it gets taken out which is functionality i don't want

Comment: Remove padding 10px.

Comment: Why have the other links if they won't be displayed anyways?

Comment: @JordanS the number of links varies depending on the day, some it may be 5, others it may be 50, plan on adding a dropdown for the overflow when it exists

Comment: Gotcha. Design for 5 then.

Comment: right, but when it's more than 5 i want it to span across with as many as possible.  With your current update it takes away the overflow

Answer (score 0):

Jordan above is correct. Also you have unnecessary CSS declarations.

```
.navigation a.active-link {
    ***background-border: #red;
    border-style: solid;***
    border-bottom: solid white;
    color: black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

You can declare like this, and remove padding for border to show.

```
.navigation a.active-link {
    border-bottom:9px solid red;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: this is closer, but my goal is to have the bottom line not be there, you still see the red and black in this example, if i change the red to white, it still shows the black on the higlighted

Comment: @JordanS guess I didn't clarify, trying to accomplish something like this http://imgur.com/a/s0ma3

Comment: Alright, I see what you are going for now. Rephrase your question above with the picture link and what you are trying to accomplish and I'll update my answer with those results.